# "System Error 53" trapping in Windows batch file?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I am writing a batch file which will go out to several users' computers and pull some log files back to my own; however, I am trying to figure out how to 'trap' cases when their computer is offline and I receive a 'System Error 53' message.  Here is an example of the command I am iterating:

```
:Lea
robocopy "\\jcjcjq1\c$\Program Files\PigCHAMP\logs" "C:\Users\mikec\Documents\@Department\Financial Services\Service Requests\PigChamp_Logs" /XO
ECHO "Lea's Logs - Copy Complete"
PAUSE
```

I have tried using IF ERRORLEVEL ... type of trapping but I'm thinking that the system will keep retrying when it reaches a SEL 53 and won't break out to return an ERRORLEVEL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to try the robocopy at all if their computer is offline, try something like this:

```
ping -n 1 jcjcjq1 >nul && robocopy "\\jcjcjq1\c$\Program Files\PigCHAMP\logs" "C:\Users\mikec\Documents\@Department\Financial Services\Service Requests\PigChamp_Logs" /XO
```